# Eliminate table data space

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

My column 'email' is auto filled by columns 'firstname'.'lastname' e.g:
'John' 'Doe' ------> john.doe@example, but some people have multiple first names like: 'John Michael' 'Doe' -------> john michael.doe@example, how do I close that space in the first name?

[image]

Here is the code for that specific row:

```
<td> <?=strtolower($row['fname'])?>.<?=strtolower($row['lname'])?‌​>@cubao.sti.edu </td>
```

Comment: in js? in php? what does your code look like? General answer: use a regular expression replacing the space with whatever you want...

Comment: The question needs better clarification of the problem. Follow instructions from http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `str_replace([' '], [''], $formValues['firstname']).$formValues['lastname'])`

Answer (score 0):

Elimination of white space :

```
$clean_data = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $true_value_got_from_user);
```

In this case you can put $first_name in preg replace and you will get clean data as output

Additionally : This will also replace unwanted data like  special characters and anything else than alphabets and special characters like (. , " " [] {}  etc. ) which are not really in first name.

If you ever wanted that first name should not contain numeric like 0-9 then delete 0-9 statement and your output will be a clean alphabet string.